# wavecom modem stk every function work perfectly for first time, not others time. using AT command & C#

Tags: c#, modem

```
AT+STGR=3,19000
> 
OK
+STIN: 99
```

I am working with wavecom modem,that is working fine for every option at first time. but after first time it always return +STIN 99. That means session time out. I can not understand where is the wrong. modem or serialport connection. I used port.BaudRate = 115200.I am using C# and AT commands.Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Is your code sending a return at the end of the command?

Comment: +STIN: 9

+STGI: "sending SMS"

OK

+STIN: 99 it is return for first time. that is i want. but others time return only +STIN 99 . thanks for your response.

Comment: You need to add a '\n' at end of each command you send  or use WriteLine().

Comment: – jdweng, I am using port.WriteLine();. But I don't understand why its work at first time and not others time. If any problem is occurred then why not first time. has any thing on serial port.

Comment: Make sure the serial port settings have handshaking turned off (both software and hardware), 8 bit, and No Parity.  Writeline sends both 0x0D (return) and 0x0A (linefeed).  The linefeed is ignored that is why you display is showing the OK on a separate line.  Do you know why the 2nd command is missing "AT"? You need AT if the if you are putting commands on Separate Lines.  You can only leave the AT out if the commands are on the same line (no return).